# Установка arch с systemd-boot с ESP и XBOOTLDR на разных физических дисках

Tags: archlinux, systemd

Как правильно установить `systemd-boot`, если `ESP` и `XBOOTLDR` разделы находятся на разных дисках или это в принципе не возможно?
Тестировал установку в `virtual-box` и при запуске загрузчика просто появляется меню с одним пунктом для входа в `UEFI` интерфейс.
`ESP` и `XBOOTLDR` разделы были отформатированы в `FAT32`.

UPD

Нашел в [доке systemd](https://uapi-group.org/specifications/specs/boot_loader_specification/) следующее:

```
Optionally, an Extended Boot Loader Partition (XBOOTLDR partition
for short) — a partition with GPT type GUID of bc13c2ff-59e6-4262-
a352-b275fd6f7172 — may be used as the second of two locations for 
boot loader menu entries. This partition must be located on the same 
disk as the ESP.
```

Я конечно до последнего надеялся что есть возможность установить как мне нужно, но придётся по старинке ставить GRUB.
Может в будущих версиях systemd-boot добавят эту возможность.